# How to style the attributes of a label when defining a joint.dia.Link?

Tags: css, json, properties, jointjs

I looked into [`dia.Link.prototype.attr`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Link.prototype.attr) with a few examples and understand that Link attributes can be directly defined this way:

```
joint.dia.Link.define('flow.Link', {
    router: {
      name: 'normal'
    },
    connector: {
      name: 'normal'
    },
    attrs: {
      '.tool-options': {
        'data-tooltip-class-name': 'small',
        'data-tooltip': 'Inspect me',
        'data-tooltip-position': 'left'
      },
      '.marker-source': {
        fill: 'none',
        stroke: 'none'
      },
      '.connection-wrap': {
        fill: 'none'
      },
      '.connection' : {
        stroke: '#0000ff',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        strokeDasharray: '0',
        fill: 'none'
      },
      '.marker-target': {
        fill: '#0000ff',
        stroke: '#0000ff',
        d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z'
      },
    }
});
```

But is there a way I can define in here the default [`dia.Link.prototype.label`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Link.prototype.label) attributes? E.g.:

```
joint.dia.Link.define('flow.Link', {
    labels: {
      '.label': {
        position: 1, // label at the target
        attrs: {
          text: { fill: 'blue', text: 'My default link label' },
          rect: { fill: 'yellow' },
        }
      }
    },
   // other properties ...
});
```

I tried several variations of the above code without success, but since `.labels` is a group of link, wouldn't something like this be possible?

An alternative to this I attempted was to programmatically style the first default label through `link.label(index, properties, opt)`, but once I add, for example, one more label to the link through the inspector, both labels attributes are lost (the former and the added one)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it is not possible to change the default label attributes (unless the [dia.LinkView.prototype.updateLabels()](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/master/src/joint.dia.link.js#L511-L529) method is overriden). I've created an [issue](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/issues/796) in the JointJS repository.

If you add labels through the `ui.Inspector` plugin, you can modify the labels inspector definition, so that every new label has the desired properties. For that use the `defaultValue` field option and make the inspector field invisible as shown in the example below.

```
labels: {
  type: 'list',
  item: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      attrs: {
        text: {
          text: {
            type: 'text',
            defaultValue: 'label',
          },
          // `labels/{n}/attrs/text/fill` fake field
          fill: {
            type: 'text',
            // The value of the property,
            // which is set when a new label is created
            defaultValue: 'blue',
            // Make this field invisible
            // So the user won't be able to change it
            attrs: { '.field': { style: 'display:none' }}
          }
        },
        rect: {
          // `labels/{n}/attrs/rect/fill` fake field
          fill: {
            type: 'text',
            defaultValue: 'yellow',
            attrs: { '.field': { style: 'display:none' }}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is one small setback with this alternative though, if the link is automatically added with a label with a few different properties without going through the inspector, all the attributes must be hardcoded into that link through `link.label(index, properties, opt)` (they will not be retrieved from the inspector's defaults).